# Using pointers to change a matrix

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, matrix, reversi

In our c course, the teacher has given us a mini project to build a "Reversi" game. I'm having trouble building the board.

```
#define Size 8
int main()
{
    char Board[Size][Size] = { {" "} };
    resetBoard(Board);
    printBoard(Board);
    printf("\n");
    getch();
}
void resetBoard(int** board)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < Size; j++)
        {
            *(board + (i * Size + j)) = 'x';
        }
    }
}
void printBoard(int board[Size][Size])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < Size; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", board[i][j]);
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I've checked the program and the program gets:

> Run-time check failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'Board' was corrupted

when it changes the first X on the third row.
For example, if I run the program till the end of the 2d row (16),
I wont get this error.

Comment: When you compile do you get any warnings? You should, and it's important you read and fix them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there may be problem with initialization of your board as type of char and working with pointers and array of type int in your functions. Char has size of 1 byte and int has bigger size depending on platform (4 bytes most of the times). This will cause memory problems with manipulation and looping over your array.

In your case, it looks like you have looped over whole allocated memory after 2 rows because you used pointers of type int. Int is in your case probably 4 times bigger than char resulting in looping over whole of your data structure of type char 4 times quicker as you expected.

Comment: alright , that's definitely the answer. thank you, wasn't paying attention :)

Comment: Now that I have changed the type, it appears that I have a problem with the reset board function. mind trying to help me with it ? :)

Comment: It seems you are you forgot to use one * before board variable in your inner loop. It should look like this: `*((*board) + (i * Size + j)) = 'x';` because your board variable is of type pointer to pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You got a bunch of errors in your code. See inline comments.

```
    //Use all capitals for defines
#define BOARD_SIZE 8

//Just reset the whole array to spaces.. No need to traverse byte by byte.
void resetBoard(char* board) {
    //memset version
    //memset(board, ' ', (BOARD_SIZE*BOARD_SIZE)*sizeof(char));

    //non memset version
    for (int i=0; i<(BOARD_SIZE*BOARD_SIZE); i++) *board++='x';
}

void printBoard(char *board) {
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; j++){
            //Access the 2D array like this (y * width of array + x)
            printf("%c", board[i*BOARD_SIZE+j]);
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

//Don't start a name using capitals.. Later when you program c++ or similar you will understand :-)
int main()
{
    //This is a more dynamic memory model and is not allocated on the stack.. (free when done!!)
    char *board=(char*)malloc(BOARD_SIZE*BOARD_SIZE);
    //there are several ways of working with arrays.. No need to complicate stuff if not needed.
    //Just point out the first byte of the array.. (See the methods takes a char pointer and that is what's passed the methods)
    if (board) {
        resetBoard(board);
        //Test to see if it works
        board[1*BOARD_SIZE+2]='0';
        printBoard(board);
        free(board);
    } else {
        printf("Out of memory!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Or bling it like it's 2020!

```
#define B 16 //Define the size of the 2d matrix
void printMatrix(char*b){for(int i=-1;i<B*B-1;(++i+1)%B?printf("%c ",b[i%B*B+i/B]):printf("%c\n",b[i%B*B+i/B])){}} //Print the 2d matrix
int main(){
    char b[B*B]={[0 ...B*B-1]='x'}; //Reserve the 2d matrix space and set all entries to 'x'
    printMatrix(&b[0]); //pass the pointer to the print 2d matrix method
    return 0; //Done!
}
```

Or 2021 ;-) (A 2d array)

```
#define B 32
void p(char b[B][B]){for(int i=-1;i<B*B-1;(++i+1)%B?printf("%c ",b[i%B][i/B]):printf("%c\n",b[i%B][i/B])){}}
int main(){
    char b[B][B]={[0 ...B-1][0 ...B-1]='x'};
    p(&b[0]);
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for trying to help. I accidentally used the wrong type on the function, as Jakub said :)

Comment: @AndersCedronius thank you very much !! rly helped me. we haven't yet learned the memset func, so I will be glad for an explanation about it if you can, or another way to do it

Comment: @RotemHeinig memset basically works like this... memset (a_pointer, the_value_to_set, number_of_bytes_to_set). just write 'man memset' in your terminal for more verbose information.

memset(void *b, int c, size_t len);

DESCRIPTION
     The memset() function writes len bytes of value c (converted to an
     unsigned char) to the string b.

Comment: Interesting thing to notice is, that when you use functions like malloc or memset to allocate your data structure, it is allocated in heap part of memory. If you use static allocation of array like you did: `char Board[Size][Size] = { {" "} };` - it is allocated in stack memory.

Comment: @JakubHubert and RotemHeinig... Added a memset alternative and if you want a more dynamic memory allocation model.

Answer (score 1):

@RotemHeinig. Your code has many deficiencies. Bellow is an example reformating your example. Maybe, it will give you an idea of how to improve to work:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define Size 8

void resetBoard(char board[][Size]);
void printBoard(char board[][Size]);

int main()
{
    char Board[Size][Size];
    resetBoard(Board);
    printBoard(Board);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

void resetBoard(char board[][Size])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < Size; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = 'x';
        }
    }
 }

 void printBoard(char board[][Size])
 {
     for (size_t i = 0; i < Size; i++)
     {
         for (size_t j = 0; j < Size; j++)
         {
              printf("%c ", board[i][j]);
              printf(" ");
         }
         printf("\n");
     }
  }
```

Compiling this code using **gcc** on my machine looks like:

```
gcc -std=c11 -Wall reversi.c -o a.out
```

And the execution gives:

```
./a.out
x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x
```

I hope you find inspiration from here on.

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for answering. The answers to this exercise should be with pointers, as the teacher said. thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

below is the *pointer* version of my previous suggestion:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define Size 8

void resetBoard(char *board, int size);
void printBoard(char *board, int size);

int main()
{
    char *Board = (char *)malloc(Size*Size*sizeof(char));
    resetBoard(Board, Size);
    printBoard(Board, Size);
    printf("\n");
   free(Board);

    return 0;
}

void resetBoard(char *board, int size)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            *(board +i*size + j) = 'x';
        }
    }
 }

 void printBoard(char *board, int size)
 {
      for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
           for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j++)
           {
                printf("%c ", *(board +i*size + j));
           }
           printf("\n");
      }
  }
```

The compile (on my machine) looks again, like:

```
gcc -std=c11 -Wall reversi.c -o a.out
```

and the execution gives:

```
./a.out
x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x 
x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x
```

Comment: Thank you mate ! Much appreciated.